# knockout.js and sorted array on object

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

Can I do a foreach on a function that takes an array object and sorts it.  I know I can do a dependent observable, but I have an array of an array coming from the mapping plugin.

```
foreach: sortList($array)
```

Comment: What do you mean you have an array of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes... Here's a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/sHQvV/

It shows three usages of foreach:

1) Plain
2) Function returning array
3) Object with data property containing an array

The [foreach documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) describes this.